# (R) How to append each item of a list to CSV preceded by the list item's name?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list that contains some automatically generated writeups of some data I scraped off TripAdvisor. The name of each item on the list is the name of the hotel. So a sample list item would look like:

> $"Holiday Inn Express & Suites Dayton South Franklin"
>
> [1] "The Holiday Inn Express & Suites Dayton South Franklin is located
> at 851 Commerce Center Dr,  ..."

I then have a lapply function that takes each writeup from the list and appends it to a CSV file.

```
lapply(writeups, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'writeups.csv', append= T, sep=',', row.names = F ))
```

The problem is that when it appends each list item to the CSV, it prints out an "x" on the line above the writeup.

> x
>
> writeup1
>
> x
>
> writeup2
>
> x

I can't quite figure out a way to change the x to the name of the list item. Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops aren't nice looking but I think it could help you in this case.

```
for(i in 1:length(your.list)){
  d<-paste0('\n\n',names(your.list)[i],'\n\n')
  capture.output(cat(d),file='writeups.csv',append=T)
  write.table(your.list[i],file='writeups.csv',append= T, sep=',', row.names = F)
}
```

The first command line inside the loop get the name of item[i] in the list, storing it at the beginning.

I hope it helps you,

Regards.

Comment: I needed to make one change to make it work (it needed to change col.names to F in the write.table statement, otherwise it was still writing the column name in between the list name and the list item), but your suggestion did eventually get the job done.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set `col.names = F` in `write.table()`

```
lapply(writeups, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'writeups.csv', append= T, sep=',', row.names = F, col.names = F ))
```